# image paste on page wherever the mouse moves

Tags: javascript, html, mousemove

I wanted to create a code for a website where an image would follow the cursor and paste itself on the page wherever the mouse would go. I am sure many have experienced this effect, when your computer crashed and you would drag a window around a screen and it would just leave a trail behind itself.

[jsfiddle - Example follow mouse](http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/SYwba/light/)

**HTML :**

```
<img class="logo" src="//ssl.gstatic.com/images/logos/google_logo_41.png" alt="Google">
```

**JS :**

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    $('.logo').offset({
        left: e.pageX,
        top: e.pageY + 20
    });
});
```

This is halfway there, I just want the Google logo to stay on the page, even after the mouse moves away from the place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SYwba/560/)**

You should add `position:absolute` to img style if you want to control it using coordinate (X & Y).

**CSS :**

```
.logo{
    position: absolute;
}
```

You can store the `img` in js variable and clone it in `onmousemove` function, and finally append it to the body.

**JS :**

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    var logo ='<img class="logo" src="//ssl.gstatic.com/images/logos/google_logo_41.png" alt="Google">';

    $("body").append(
        $(logo).clone().offset({
            left: e.pageX,
            top: e.pageY + 20
        })
    );
});
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you! However, is it possible to overlay the images on top of one another. This just adds more images as you move your mouse.

Comment: Ur welcome @PiotrIrving, can you show me an example of what you want to achieve ?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BJGBH.png / http://i.stack.imgur.com/EA0H8.jpg - an effect like this, but on a webpage

Comment: Yes i see, but that exactly what i have in the example on my fiddle. the difference between my example and your example (pictures) is that your img is `png` what means with transparent background, take a look at **[my same JS fiddle with jpg image](http://jsfiddle.net/SYwba/563/)**.